# Figure out what Activity is currently active in Android (non-programmatically)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

A lot of time when I'm debugging my app, I click around and end up in an activity, but I'm not 100% sure which one. This happens in my latest project, which I inherited from someone else.

I want an easy method of figuring out which activity I'm currently in, not programmatically for the program to know, but for my brain. I see ActivityManager does say something like "Displayed activity foo" in logcat, but sometimes this message quickly goes away because of other logging.

Ideally, the current activity class would be displayed somewhere at all times, or there would be something similar to Firebug's Inspect button but for activities. I looked around the DDMS perspective and didn't find it there either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hierarchyviewer is fine for this, but perhaps a bit heavy duty.

Try this from command line:

```
adb logcat |grep "Starting activity"
```

Every time you start a new activity there will a line printed.

Comment: I should add that you can see all sorts of other interesting stuff by grepping all log messages from the ActivityManager, instead of just starting activities. Try "adb logcat|grep ActivityManager".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I've understood you, but there's a tool called [hierarchy-viewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) to debug the user interface

Comment: That's pretty close - indeed, it shows all currently running activities. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to highlight which one is active now, so if the app starts 4-5 activities, I won't be able to tell which one is focused. I was hoping for a much lighter version of this within Eclipse or maybe the emulator itself.

Comment: @Artem Russakovskii As Robert says you can search in the logcat for Starting Activity. You can apply easily filters in the DDMS on logcat, so the easiest thing to do would be to apply a filter searching for "Starting activity" and seeing what's on the last line.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers, but the adb with grep solution kind of wins over as it's more practical. This is a close 2nd though!

Answer (score 1):

You can also add `this` to the watch expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the logcat on *ActivityManager* is the most easy way to figure this out.